# Equinumerous sets, power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

[image]

(ZF) Prove that for an arbitrary set A the following holds:

1. $ \bar{A} = \bar{A ∪  [{A}]} ⇒ \bar{P(A)} =\bar{(P(A) ∪ [P(A)])}$ ;
2. $ \bar{A} =  \bar{(A ∪ [A])} ⇒  \bar{P(P(A))} =  \bar{P(P(A) × P(P(A))} $.

What I have made so far is:

1. By def, A and B are equinumerous if there is a bijection f: A->B.

Let  $ x  \subset A =>x \subset \bar{A ∪ {A}} $.

Then $ Dom(f) \subseteq A$   and $Rng(f) \subseteq \bar{A ∪  [{A}]} $. Obviously this is injection since $x\subset A$ or $x \equiv sing A $.

But because $ x \in A \Rightarrow x\in P(A).$ But $f(x)\subseteq P(A)$ and $f(x)\subseteq A\Rightarrow f(x) \in P(A)\cup [A].$ Hence there is a function $g$ for which $g(f(x))$ is $P(A)\mapsto (P(A)∪[P(A)])¯  $;
And hence they are equinumerous.

2. We know that $ (X)^(B∪C)=X^B×X^C $. But afterwards I do not know what to do.

With [x] I denote the singleton of the set x.
I am sorry for the syntax, but I am a beginner in Math Text Editors.

I will be really thankful to anyone who share the ideas he/she has about the problem since I am stuck on it.
I tried to explain what I think that will be useful with the solution even though I am not quite sure what to do about 2.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: My edit was only for missing dollars. I don't understand your notation. What are $[A],\, \bar A$ and $sing A$ ? BTW if you want an overline over a sequence of characters, encase them in braces, e.g. \overline {4+Bob} yields $\overline {4+Bob}$. Note the mandatory space after the last letter of "\overline". This also applies for many other LaTex  commands, e.g. for fonts. And you can use \implies for $\implies$ and \to for $\to$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you so much for the edit. I submit the picture itself, you can find it in this link:  https://ibb.co/nPqmw7S. I hope that you will understand the idea after seeing it.

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but there should not have to be a space after a LaTeX command before the opening `{` -- for me, `\overline{4 + Bob}` and `\overline {4 + Bob}` render the same thing: $\overline{4 + Bob}, \overline {4 + Bob}$.

Comment: I dk what a double overline would mean in set theory either.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That there exists a bijection from the first set tothe second,

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: The double vinculum is an old notation for cardinality.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hello! Because I saw your comment and the fact that nobody yet has decided to help, if you can come up with an idea, would you please share it with me?

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid that your argument for $(1)$ simply doesn’t make much sense. You start by saying that if $x\subseteq A$, then $x\subseteq\overline{\overline{A\cup\{A\}}}$. However, this makes no sense, because $\overline{\overline{A\cup\{A\}}}$ has not been given an independent meaning as a set: it’s just part of the notation that you’re using to say when there is a bijection between two sets. What is true, and what I suspect you meant, is that if $x\subseteq A$, then $x\subseteq A\cup\{A\}$.

You then conclude from this that $\operatorname{dom}f\subseteq A$ and $\operatorname{ran}f\subseteq\overline{\overline{A\cup\{A\}}}$. There are multiple problems with this, starting with the fact that you have not defined $f$. We can guess that you mean the embedding $f:A\to A\cup\{A\}$, though the fact that you were originally looking at **subsets** $x$ of $A$ rather than **elements** of $A$ actually suggests that $f$ is a map from $\wp(A)$ to $\wp(A\cup\{A\})$, in which case the domain of $f$ is **not** a subset of $A$ but rather of $\wp(A)$. And in any case you are once again treating $\overline{\overline{A\cup\{A\}}}$ as if it were a set.

Then you say that $x\in A$ implies that $x\in\wp(A)$; this is simply false. And I can make no sense of the last sentence (about $g$).

You want to show that if there is a bijection between $A$ and $A\cup\{A\}$, then there is a bijection between $\wp(A)$ and $\wp(A)\cup\{\wp(A)\}$. The natural way to start is:

> Let $f:A\to A\cup\{A\}$ be a bijection.

**The rest is completely revised and corrected.**

To get a bijection between $\wp(A)$ and $\wp(A)\cup\{\wp(A)\}$ we can use the fact that there is an obvious bijection $s$ from $A$ to $\mathscr{S}=\big\{\{a\}:a\in A\big\}$: let

$$s:A\to\mathscr{S}:a\mapsto\{a\}\,.$$

The map $f$ is a bijection from $A$ to a set, $A\cup\{A\}$, that is $A$ together with one extra element, so we should be able to use it and $s$ to get a bijection from $\mathscr{S}$ to the set $\mathscr{S}\cup\{\wp(A)\}$, which is $\mathscr{S}$ together with one extra element. Specifically, let

$$\hat f=f\circ s^{-1}:\mathscr{S}\to A\cup\{A\}\,,$$

and let

$$g:A\cup\{A\}\to\mathscr{S}\cup\{\wp(A)\}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
s(x),&\text{if }x\in A\\
\wp(A),&\text{if }x=A\,;
\end{cases}$$

$\hat f$, being a composition of bijections, is a bijection, $g$ is easily seen to be a bijection as well.

Now let

$$\begin{align*}
&h:\wp(A)\to\wp(A)\cup\{\wp(A)\}:\\
&\quad X\mapsto\begin{cases}
g\left(\hat f(X)\right),&\text{if }X\in\mathscr{S}\\
X,&\text{if }X\in\wp(A)\setminus\mathscr{S}\,;
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

it’s not hard to check that $h$ is also a bijection.

Comment: Hello and Thank you so much I really appreciate the help! g is injection: let x_1 and x_2 be an arbitrary chosen sets from P(A), and assume  x_1 = x_2. Then g(x_1)=x_1 and g(x_2)=x_2, thus g(x_1)=g(x_2). This proves that g is injection.g is surjection: since g i defined for every x∈℘(A), then g(x)=x which is mapping over ℘(A). If x={A} ,then g(x)={℘(A)} , so g maps from Dom_g to ℘(A)∪{℘(A)}  . This g is bijection.

Comment: h is injection:Let x_1 and x_2 be two elements in x or every x∈℘(A), such that y_1=y_2. Then f[x_1]=f(y_1)=y_1 anf f[x_2]=f(y_2)=y_2, then f[x_1]=f[x_2], h is injection.h is surjection since for every x ∈℘(A), there is y' such that f(y')=h(x), but f is surjection, then h is surjection.

Comment: Would you please tell me wether those arguments work?

Comment: @Tiki: I have to apologize: my mind must have wandered badly when I was writing that up, because the definition that I gave for $g$ makes no sense: $g$ is defined as if its domain were $\wp(A)\cup\big\{\{A\}\big\}$ instead of $\wp(A\cup\{A\})$. It’s very late — almost 04:00 here — so I’m going to wait until tomorrow to think about how to fix it for you.

Comment: @Tiki: And I have now fixed it (barring further mental hiccups).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It was indeed very late, solving math problems until dawn. However, thank you so much for the fixed solution, will look at it. I really appreciate your help!