# Cardinality of Set and its Power Set Singleton

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

[image]

I know that I should prove that there is a bijection between the two sides but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Could you give more attempts you have tried?

Comment: @HanulJeon Yes. Let f:A→A∪{A} be a bijection. Define g:℘(℘(A))→℘(℘(A)) and try to prove that it is a bijection. And then composition of f and g is a bijection. Also maybe Kuratowski def to rewrite the right side. But I am still unable to solve it.

Comment: The notation I am used to is a bit different so please tell me if I am not undertanding something well. On the left hand side, we can understand that equality as "the cardinality of $A$ is infinite" right? And the right hand side is $\kappa=\kappa\otimes\kappa$ where $\kappa=card(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)))$

Comment: @AdrianPortilloFernández: The lefthand side does imply that $A$ is Dedekind infinite, but the old-fashioned notation and [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980313/equinumerous-sets-power-set) suggest that for the OP it really just means that there is a bijection between $A$ and $A\cup\{A\}$; it’s not clear what consequences of that are actually available to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is asking the followings (in the standard terminology): if $X$ is Dedekind-infinite, then $2^{2^{|X|}}=\left(2^{2^{|X|}}\right)^2$. You can prove it by using simple cardinal arithmetic:
observe that $$\left(2^{2^{|X|}}\right)^2=2^{2^{|X|}\cdot 2}=2^{2^{|X|+1}}.$$ By the assumption, we have $2^{2^{|X|+1}}=2^{2^{|X|}}$.

Comment: @HanualJeon I know that I can solve it this way, and I already did, but I prefer without arithmetic, because this way the problem is not about constructing functions, but about raising to power. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @tiki Using cardinal arithmetic is just constructing a function in disguise. You can see how to construct the bijection by analyzing the proof of equalities about cardinal arithmetic, e.g., proving $2^{|A|+1}=2^{|A|}\cdot 2$ is done by constructing a bijection from $\mathcal{P}(A\cup\{A\})$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)\times 2$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Here is an outline of a proof that does not assume any knowledge of cardinal arithmetic.

Show that there is a bijection between $\wp(A)$ and $\wp(A)\times\{\wp(A)\}$. Then show that $\wp(A)$ and $\wp(A)\times\{\wp(A)\}$ are disjoint and use this fact to define a bijection between $\wp(\wp(A))\times\wp(\wp(A))$ and $\wp\big(\wp(A)\cup\big(\wp(A)\times\{\wp(A)\}\big)\big)$.

The next step is to define a bijection between

$$\wp\left(\wp(A)\cup(\wp(A)\times\{\wp(A)\}\big)\right)$$

and $\wp\big(\wp(A\cup\{A\})\big)$.

Finally, define a bijection between $\wp\big(\wp(A\cup\{A\})\big)$ and $\wp(\wp(A))$ and put the pieces together to get the desired bijection between $\wp(\wp(A))$ and $\wp(\wp(A))\times\wp(\wp(A))$.